# How to change SUMMARY title of cart page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

I need to change text SUMMARY to BASKET SUMMARY. Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cart summary text is set in

```
 vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
```

To change this text extend the layout with a custom module or theme and change the summary block text argument

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.summary.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">Basket Summary</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but your suggestion will change whole website Summary Text to Basket Summary. I just need to change it for cart page.

Comment: Ok I will update the answer.

Comment: Works Fine. Thanks mate! 